# How to send data from servlet to all logged In users

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0, servlet-listeners

My requirement is admin should send data to all logged in users. I have one servlet first one user send login HTTP req and gets login success response from servlet now session for this user is started.Similarly other user logs in. Now admin which is also one user can login and see two users user1 and user2 logged in. Admin should send data to all logged in users. Servlet should push data to that user without users HTTP request. kindly note during session user won't send any other HTTP request.

Instead of comet I tried to store response obj's of each logged in user and later using that obj tried to post data back to user but that didn't worked.

Please check below code: **LoginServlet.java**

```
    public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        ServletContext sc;

        protected ArrayList<HttpServletResponse> connections = new ArrayList<HttpServletResponse>();

        public LoginServlet() {
            super();

        }

        public void init() throws ServletException {
            super.init();

            sc = getServletContext();

        }

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        }

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


            synchronized (connections) {
                connections.add(response);
            }
            ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
            Integer x = (Integer) sc.getAttribute("hit");

            if (x == null)
                x = 1;
            else
                x++;
            sc.setAttribute("hit", x);

            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");

            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

            session.setAttribute("username", username);
            session.setAttribute("password", password);
            response.setContentType("text/html");

            ArrayList<LoggedInUser> loggedInUsers = (ArrayList<LoggedInUser>) sc
                    .getAttribute("users");

            if (loggedInUsers == null) {
                System.out.println("loggedInUsers creates");
                loggedInUsers = new ArrayList<LoggedInUser>();

            }
            loggedInUsers.add(new LoggedInUser(username, password));

            sc.setAttribute("users", loggedInUsers);

            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            System.out.println("loggedInUsers ==>" + loggedInUsers.size());
            if (username != null && username.equals("admin")) {
                out.println("Admin Login Success");
                ServletContext scx = getServletContext();
                Integer xx = (Integer) scx.getAttribute("hit");

                out.println("<H1>Users visited " + xx + "</h1>");
                loggedInUsers = (ArrayList<LoggedInUser>) sc.getAttribute("users");

                for (int i = 0; i <= loggedInUsers.size() - 1; i++) {
                    LoggedInUser LoggedInUser = loggedInUsers.get(i);
                    out.println(LoggedInUser.getmUsername()+ "<br>");
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < connections.size(); i++) {

                    try {

                        LoggedInUser LoggedInUser = loggedInUsers.get(i);
                        PrintWriter writer = connections.get(i).getWriter();
                        System.out.println("inside loope " + i + "\n" + writer);
                        writer.println("MESSAGE FROM ADMIN HERE" + "<br>");

                        writer.flush();
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log("IOExeption sending message", e);
                    }

                }

            } else {
                out.println("Welcome   " + username + "   Login Success");
            }
        }
    }
```

As soon as user logs in stored resp obj in arraylist.

```
synchronized (connections) {
    connections.add(response);
}
```

And later using that obj got the printwriter obj.

```
PrintWriter writer = connections.get(i).getWriter();
```

**Questions:**

1. How to send one specific msg to all logged In users?
2. Without comet can we achieve this?

Kindly correct the code if anything wrong I have done and help with other suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Hey, what a java-presentation-technology do you use? Java-Server-Faces, Wicket, JSP, Struts, Spring?

Comment: @ peter can't we store response obj and send message using that obj?

Comment: @peter simple servlet-jsp using tomcat

Comment: The connections are offline when the servlet's work is done! You should store the message in the session. Do you using javascript like jQuery?

Comment: So you wanted to invent new communication model under the HTTP umbrella ? ;-) "HTTP functions as a request-response protocol in the client-server computing model" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http

Answer (score 5):

> Servlet should push data to that user without users HTTP request.

That is not technically possible.  The HTTP protocol simply does not allow it.  The browser can only get a response from the server if it sends a request.  Once it has finished reading the response, it won't attempt to read anything more from its socket ... until it sends the next request.

What you could do is put some javascript into all of the pages that periodically makes an AJAX request to the server asking if there is a admin message to be displayed.

I suppose that you could also do this using COMET too.

Your current approach of keeping the last response and trying to write more data to it fails because it violates the HTTP protocol, and servlet state machine.  When the login servlet completes the original request, the response's output stream is flushed to the socket and closed.  It cannot be reopened, and even if it could, the browser wouldn't know what to do with the data you wrote.

UPDATE: there is a variation on this that could work.  It involves WebSockets ... where the client sends some special headers in the request, and the server sends a 101 response and *switches protocols* ; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: Comet or websockets or soon webRTC dataChannel

Comment: @ stephen Actually i am going to hit the URL from android application not from android browser or PC web browser. Is there any other alternate to achieve this? Through android application users will get connected and admin will push them data to all at time or to some selected users. for android we have GCM google cloud to device messaging service but that will be overhead as GCM just notifies android app about new data is available at server side so again user has to hit server to get data. So I thought why not to push data from server to user. Let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: *"So I thought why not to push data from server to user. Let me know your thoughts on this."* - My thoughts are 1) I don't know how you would do that.  2) Why make things difficult for yourself?